# Dart js-interop not working if .dart file isn't included

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

After announcing new strategy for Dart, i decided to change include from

```
<script type="application/dart" src="/dart/script.dart"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dart/script.dart.js"></script>
```

But in that case js-interop seems broken. `dart:js.context` is empty.
Is there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing this script tag:

```dart
<script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

There is also an open issue to fix this http://dartbug.com/23005

Comment: I have this tag, just didn't mention it because it's not changed. Thanks for issue link, I'll follow it.

Comment: It didn't work for me at first but after adding this tag it did. Maybe it is related that you have the script in a subdirectory?